# React-Native app hangs on splash on iOS, but on on Android works just fine

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

I have the app that uses React-Native 0.62.3 and it does not run on iOS. It launches, receives the bundle from metro and does nothing but keeps showing the splash screen. Here's the run log:

```
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Inspector
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Preferences
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin React
flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin Network
2020-10-15 15:30:32.116261+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:792251] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000aebe00> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2020-10-15 15:30:32.326978+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793032] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2020-10-15 15:30:32.410529+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:792251] [native] Running application fastboss_mobile_rn ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2020-10-15 15:30:39.443156+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793034] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C6.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2020-10-15 15:30:39.450465+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793034] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C6.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2020-10-15 15:30:39.452317+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793033] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C6] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2020-10-15 15:30:39.452482+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793033] TCP Conn 0x600003cf4a50 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2020-10-15 15:30:39.975074+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793119] [javascript] Require cycle: components/Dashboard/content/index.js -> components/Dashboard/content/Customers.js -> components/Dashboard/content/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-10-15 15:30:39.980483+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793119] [javascript] Require cycle: components/Dashboard/index.js -> components/Dashboard/Menu.js -> components/Dashboard/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-10-15 15:30:39.986365+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793119] [javascript] Require cycle: components/index.js -> components/Dashboard/index.js -> components/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
2020-10-15 15:30:40.029406+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793119] [javascript] Running "fastboss_mobile_rn" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
2020-10-15 15:30:40.166056+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793284] [native] Manifest does not exist - creating a new one.

(null)
2020-10-15 15:30:40.236534+0300 fastboss_mobile_rn[60669:793119] [javascript] 'token on start up:', null
```

I've tried to google about `nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C6.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]`, but for me it seems like all the reasults are about this line being looped, but in my case it appears only 2 times.

Also the last log string is console.log() from the app, so i guess it kinda tries to work, i don't know..

I'd be pretty happy if you could tell me what is possibly wrong, because I ran out of ideas what can I do about it

xcode v12.0.1
ios 14 simulator

If I can provide any useful for you info, let me know

Comment: Also having this issue, I like you am running on a simulator, so the answer below doesn't make sense. If I figure this out, I'll post back here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and noticed it was because my iPhone and my Mac running XCode were on different WiFi networks. Verify that both devices are on the same network.

Comment: This is not the case, I have set xcode and iphone on same wifi but still not connected